# In WCF Message Inspection, how to find the value of an input parameter within a Message object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, extensibility

In WCF Message Inspection, how to find the value of an input parameter within a Message object?

I'm using a MessageInspector and have the below class:

```
public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        // TODO: how to find the value of the siteName parameter if exists?

        Console.WriteLine("Incoming request: {0}", request);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }
}
```

How could I extract the value of the siteName input parameter of my webmethod? all of my webmethods have siteName input parameter.

Answer (score 10):

The conversion between the message and the parameters is done by a message formatter. You can do that, but once you read the message to get the value of the parameter, the message has been *used*, so you need to recreate it before passing it along to WCF (which is why in the message inspector, the request is passed by reference, so you can replace it if you indeed need to consume it).

As @burning_LEGION mentioned, a parameter inspector is likely the best option for your scenario. On the inspector itself it doesn't have the parameter names, but you can get them from the operation description, which you have in your behavior which you'll use to add the parameter inspector. The code below shows one way how it can be done.

```
public class StackOverflow_15637994
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Echo(string text);
        [OperationContract]
        int Execute(string op, int x, int y);
        [OperationContract]
        bool InOutAndRefParameters(int x, ref int y, out int z);
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public string Echo(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }

        public int Execute(string op, int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }

        public bool InOutAndRefParameters(int x, ref int y, out int z)
        {
            z = y;
            y = x;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class MyInspector : IParameterInspector
    {
        string[] inputParameterNames;
        string[] outputParameterNames;
        public MyInspector(string[] inputParameterNames, string[] outputParameterNames)
        {
            this.inputParameterNames = inputParameterNames;
            this.outputParameterNames = outputParameterNames;
        }

        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation: {0}", operationName);
            Console.WriteLine("  Result: {0}", returnValue);
            for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  [out] {0}: {1}", this.outputParameterNames[i], outputs[i]);
            }
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operation: {0}", operationName);
            for (int i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", this.inputParameterNames[i], inputs[i]);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
    public class MyBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                string[] inputParamNames = operation.Messages[0].Body.Parts
                    .OrderBy(mpd => mpd.Index)
                    .Select(mpd => mpd.Name)
                    .ToArray();
                string[] outputParamNames = null;
                if (operation.Messages.Count > 1)
                {
                    outputParamNames = operation.Messages[1].Body.Parts
                        .OrderBy(mpd => mpd.Index)
                        .Select(mpd => mpd.Name)
                        .ToArray();
                }

                MyInspector inspector = new MyInspector(inputParamNames, outputParamNames);
                endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations[operation.Name].ParameterInspectors.Add(inspector);
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<ITest> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITest>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        ITest proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        proxy.Echo("Hello");
        proxy.Execute("foo", 2, 5);
        int z;
        int y = 2;
        proxy.InOutAndRefParameters(3, ref y, out z);

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can deserialize `Message` and use any field, but using [IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector.aspx?ppud=4) is better

Comment: thanks, I wanted to use IParameterInspector but it doesn't have input parameter names, only values so it's not possible to find out which parameter is the siteName using IParameterInspector.

Comment: use reflection - get parameters names by string method name

Comment: is it more efficient than Xml XPath on the Message?

Comment: The parameter names aren't an input to IParameterInspector because the position on the parameters within object [] inputs is fixed based on the service contract. They are assuming that you can determine which input is "siteName" by reflecting on the interface that the service exposes.

Comment: You don't even need to use reflection - the parameter names are given in the operation description. Notice that reflection can fail - it's possible that a method parameter named something, and the *message* parameter something else (via the `[MessageParameter]` attribute.